# Multiple raw_input and searching

Tags: python, python-2.7

Because *programming* is one of my favorite hobbies I started a small project in python.

I'm trying to make a nutritional calculator for daily routine, see the code below:

```
# Name: nutri.py 
# Author: pyn

my_dict = {'chicken':(40, 50, 10),
        'pork':(50, 30, 20)
         }

foods = raw_input("Enter your food: ")

#explode / split the user input

foods_list = foods.split(',')

#returns a list separated by comma

print foods_list
```

What I want to do:

1. Get user input and store it in a variable
2. Search the dictionary based on user input and return the asociated values if the keys / foods exists
3. Sum these values in different nutritional chunks and return them, something like: You ate x protein, y carbs and z fat etc.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_dict = {'chicken':(40, 50, 10),
        'beef':(50, 30, 20)
         }

foods = raw_input("Enter your food: ")

#explode / split the user input

foods_list = foods.split(',')

#returns a list separated by comma

#print foods_list

nuts = [0, 0, 0]

for food in foods_list :
    if food.strip() in my_dict: 
        i = 0
        for value in  my_dict[food.strip()]:
            nuts[i] += value        
            i += 1  
print nuts  

scripts$ python nutrition.py
Enter your food: chicken, pork, beef
[90, 80, 30]


some improvements ;)
```

Comment: dude this won't work when the user will enter an incorrect input(food). I have posted one below this. U may check out that it will work for any case.

Comment: yours would not work if the user enters chicken,[space] pork :P

Answer (score 0):

This code will do all the necessary stuff u are trying to do:

```
my_dict = {'chicken':(40, 50, 10),
        'pork':(50, 30, 20)
         }

foods = raw_input("Enter your food: ")

#explode / split the user input

foods_list = foods.split(',')

#returns a list separated by comma

t=[0,0,0]

print foods_list

for i in foods_list:
    if i.strip() in my_dict:
        v=my_dict.get(i.strip())
        t[0]=t[0]+v[0]
        t[1]=t[1]+v[1]
        t[2]=t[2]+v[2]

print t
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, It checks if a food is in the dictionary and will state if its not.

```
my_dict = {'chicken':(40, 50, 10),
        'pork':(50, 30, 20)
         }

foods = raw_input("Enter your food: ")

foods_list = foods.split(',')

empty_list = []
for food in foods_list:
    if food in my_dict:
        empty_list.append(list(my_dict[food]))
    else:
        print '%s has no nutritional information and will not be included in the calculation' % food

values = [sum(x) for x in zip(*empty_list)]

print 'Total protein = %d, Total Carbs = %d, Total Fat = %d' % (values[0],values[1],values[2])
```

This outputs:

```
Enter your food: chicken,pork,pizza
pizza has no nutritional information and will not be included in the calculation
Total protein = 90, Total Carbs = 80, Total Fat = 30
```